# How to set Record Selection Formula on Crystal Reports java

Tags: java, swing, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

How do you create/set Record Selection Formula programatically on crystal reports using java? I tried searching on the internet but the only option is through IFilter which requires a Crystal Report Server. My program only uses the JRC library. Also this is a java desktop application using swing.

Comment: what do you mean by "create/set Record Selection Formula programatically"? don't you use SQL to select your data?

Comment: A vote down to this question is really disappointing. :|

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to create a crystal report of your program, you need another jar file of software.
You can create your program in NetBeans IDE and link your IDE with IReport software which is used in NetBeans for creating Reporting in java.
You get many example from internet about this.

Comment: Im sorry but this answer is quite far from my question. My program can print/display cyrstal reports already. The problem is that I only want to print certain records from the table the report is picking up from. I dont want to print all the records. In vb6, you can declare, or there is a function to put a record selection formula on the report programatically so it will filter the report. That's what I want to know. Searched it everywhere but no good

Answer (score 2):

It may be a bit late, but maybe this is useful for someone:

```
reportClientDoc.getDataDefController().getRecordFilterController().setFormulaText("your record selection formula here");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing some research about this and noticed that there are 3 methods with which you can do this:

1. Using the [`IFilter` interface](https://help.sap.com/javadocs/bip/40/ras/en/com/crystaldecisions/sdk/occa/report/data/IFilter.html) as shown in this [example](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-6304) provided by SAP

   ```
   // Set the filter string to be used as the Record Filter
   String freeEditingFilter = "{Customer.Country} = 'Canada'";
   // Retrieve the record filter for the Data Definition Controller
   IFilter iFilter = clientDoc.getDataDefController().getDataDefinition().getRecordFilter();
   // Set the filter to free editing text filter string
   iFilter.setFreeEditingText(freeEditingFilter);
   // Modify the filter through the Record Filter Controller to the report
   clientDoc.getDataDefController().getRecordFilterController().modify(iFilter);
   ```

   I am using the JRC only without a Crystal Report Server and the above example worked for me.
2. As Francisco said in his answer, using the [`setFormulaText`](https://help.sap.com/javadocs/bip/40/ras/en/com/crystaldecisions/sdk/occa/report/application/FilterController.html#setFormulaText(java.lang.String)) method:

   ```
   clientDoc.getDataDefController().getRecordFilterController().setFormulaText("{Customer.Country} = 'Canada'");
   ```
3. Using parameters. Parameters can be passed to the report using code (you can use the `addDiscreteParameterValue` function in the helper class) or else they can be filled in by the user during runtime. I chose not to opt for this option because they can not be set to optional